# Some java Fundamental

Tags: java

**Update::**

**1). problem ::**

**i wrote** `System.out.println("welcom");` & 
        `System.out.println("india");`
**i want like ::** *welcome india*

**but give::**

*welcome*
*india*

Comment: Your questions are about two completely different topics.  In future, please try to keep one topic per Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Please don't revert valid edits, this question has nothing to do with android. This is a java-question. The android tag is just wrong here.

Comment: @downvoters please dont give down-vote i take your all advice and next time improve it

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**1.**

`println` always prints a newline character.  To get what you want, try:

```
System.out.print("welcome ");
System.out.print("india\n");
```

**2.**

`x++` is *post-increment*, `++x` is pre-increment.

So in:

```
int x = 5;
int y = ++x;
```

`y` will be `6`.

But in:

```
int x = 5;
int y = x++;
```

`y` will be `5`.

Comment: I really don't get why but some people seem to really struggle with those differences in 2..

Answer (score 5):

In 1:  What is the difference between System.out.print and System.out.println ?

In 2: What does the ++ operator do and when does it do it?

Answer (score 1):

```
println
```

stands for "print line" so, if you use `println` you have a "carriage return" and the next `println` will print a new line (and so on...)

`x++` is different to `++x`: the second increment variable's value and then goes on, the first goes on with statement and **then** increment variable's value.

Answer (score 1):

System.out.println("welcom"); & System.out.println("india");
 you wrote now if you want same line

```
  System.out.print("welcom "); 
  System.out.print("india");
```

And

```
x++ is Post-increment
Post-increment : add 1 to the value.
The value is returned before the increment is made, e.g.
   x = 1;
   y = x++;
Then y will hold 1 and x will hold 2
```

and

```
 ++x is pre increment
 Pre-increment : add 1 to the value.
The value is returned after the increment is made, e.g.
   x = 1;
   y = ++x;
 Then y will hold 2 and x will hold 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

try System.out.print & 1 happens before a condition/expression takes place; the other after;

Comment: Actually, in your current code snippet, both expressions evaluate to true.

Answer (score 0):

1) To print a string without printing an endline use `System.out.print()`
2)
`x++` - increment x, and return x's previous value (before increment)
`++x` - increment x, return x's current value (after increment)

These are the Post and Pre fix versions of incrementing.

Answer (score 0):

println() prints a line and anything printed after the println statement (using any print statement) is printed in the next line.

Second thing is the difference between ++x and x++. ++x increases the value of x BEFORE doing anything else in the statement (pre-increment), and x++ increases the value of x AFTER it performs anything else in the statement (post increment).

For example:

```
x = 1;
y = ++x; // value of y is 2, value of x is 2
```

but

```
x = 1;
y = x++; // value of y is 1 and x is 2
```

Answer (score 0):

`System.out.println()` has give next line as it complete statment & ++x are use for preincremet & C++ is post incremental.